WebRTC: Triggering new DTLS
I tried going through the WebRTC documentation to get any information on how to trigger new DTLS connection. I tried doing ICE restart but the fingerprint is same all the time.
Is there any API to let the WebRTC stack know that it has to trigger new DTLS  ??
